# Bubbles in canned tomato sauce

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

I put up two quarts of fresh tomatoes for sauce yesterday. They were in the hot water bath for 45 minutes. This morning they are cold & I thought ready for the cupboard.  I notice many air bubbles when I turn the jars over Should this be of a concern for my storing & eating them later on?

Comment: Welcome! For good formatting purposes, please don't use all caps for titles.

Comment: That's the right amount of processing time for quart jars of tomatoes; could just be the fruits were a little less juicy than normal so the bubbles weren't able to rise. Watch for bloating and smell carefully before eating just in case, though.

Comment: ok, thank you--will be careful when I open one  but tomatoes seem very juicy